# How to add existing files from ios app to dropbox server using sync api?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, synchronization, dropbox-api

All the documents from dropbox and other tutorials are talking about create the new files and sync with dropbox using sync api.

I have some files my app document directory and I'd like to sync them with dropbox server.

Here is what I did.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"emmy.txt"];

    DBPath *newPath = [[DBPath root] childPath:path];
    DBFile *file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:newPath error:nil];
    //[file writeString:str error:nil];

    DBFileStatus *status = file.status;
    if (!status.cached) {
        [file addObserver:self block:^() {
        }];

    }
```

The file created on dropbox but it is empty.  The file in my app has content.

How can I upload the existing files to dropbox in my app using dropbox sync api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`writeContentsOfFile`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFile.writeContentsOfFile%3ashouldSteal%3aerror%3a).